# Change color when you click over an specific canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, raphael

I'm creating dynamically canvas elements with Raphael.js, but I need change the color when the element is pressed.
I just attach the click event over each specific circle, but How I can change the color of the pressed element?

```
paper = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500);
  circs = paper.set();
  for (i = 0; i < 21; ++i)
  {
    opa = ran(3,10)/10;
    circs.push(paper.circle(ran(0,500), ran(0,500), ran(13,30)).attr({"fill-opacity": opa,
    "stroke-opacity": opa }).click(function(){
      $("#toggle").click();
      //Change color?

    }));

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what the toggle is there, may help if you produce a jsfiddle if needed.

Typically you would do something like

```
paper.circle(x,y,r).click(function(){
    this.attr({ fill: "blue", opacity: "0.5" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Raphael, but as any other jquery object you should use $(this) when in the object scope. From the Raphael docs I see you need to change the fill attribute so your code should be

$("#toggle").click();
  $(this).attr("fill", "#f00");

Hope that helps